Is there any way to be able to connect to my MacBook via SSH or screen sharing when its lid is closed?
I have a 2019 MacBook Pro that, when not in use, is charging and has a wired connection to my network using a USB-C to ethernet dongle. However, I generally keep the lid closed, and since the system is asleep, I can't do things like connect to it using ssh or screen sharing. Is there any way to set it up so that I can still connect to it even when the lid is closed?

HomePod mini or Apple TV will wake your Mac up when an ssh connection arrives. Do you have other Apple devices that run on your network?

@bmike No HomePods or Apple TVs, but I am connecting from another mac for what that's worth.

Your other Mac needs to send a WOL ping. Apple Remote Desktop can send a remote wake packet as can python scripts. Then the ssh / vnc/ ard will work.

@bmike Is there anything extra I need to do to get Apple's remote desktop client to send the WOL packet? If I just connect from the Finder while my MacBook is asleep, even using its IP address, it still won't connect.

Finder won’t work. You need the  Remote Desktop app. In that app window, select a computer list, select one or more sleeping or offline computers, then choose Manage > Wake https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/remote-desktop/apd5535ee19/mac that app is overkill for most people managing less than a dozen computers remotely. Go with python is less costly.

This must be something that Apple changes (too frequently!). In my case, I can reliably connect to my 2016 Mojave MBP when the lid is closed/sleeping from my 2023 Ventura with "shared folders", "SSH" and "screen-sharing". I can do this directly from Finder.

To wake the device, you would have to enable "Wake for network access" in the Battery settings, and send it a wake-on-LAN network packet. That can be done automatically by a Bonjour sleep proxy such as an Apple TV, an Airport base station, or a computer running a software implementation such as SleepProxyServer. You can also do it manually from a Windows host or a Mac running third-party software.
